# Evaluate definite integral with different variables at endpoint

Tags: calculus, integration

Not sure how to do this. I can do FTC questions but this one is escaping me:

Differentiate $$F(x) = \int_a^x \sec^2(xt+1) \, dt $$

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be by actually finding the antiderivative.  It's difficult to talk students out of that in problems in which the FTC is to be applied, but maybe this time it will serve us:
$$
\int_a^x \sec^2(xt+1)\,dt = \left.\vphantom{\frac11} \frac{\tan(xt+1)} x \right|_{t=a}^{t=x} = \frac{\tan(x^2+1)} x - \frac{\tan(ax+1)} x.
$$
Then
$$
\frac d {dx}\left( \frac{\tan(x^2+1) - \tan(ax+1)} x \right) = \frac{x\Big(\sec^2(x^2+1)\cdot 2x  - a\sec^2(ax+1)\Big) - (\tan(x^2+1) - \tan(ax+1))}{x^2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you! Would the method be any different if the bottom limit was 0?